# How do I deploy an Angular-Dart web app

Tags: dart, webstorm, angular-dart

After using FileZilla to ftp the files to the website, my app just shows

```
Loading....
```

...when  trying to run from a chrome browser.

I have built and tested the app in Webstorm (2017.2.3)
Do I need to do anything else other than just copy the files from the build/web directory to my host? What about the build/lib directory?
If you want to see what is happening (or not, actually), take a look at: 
http://sudoku.geobits.com/index.html

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any errors in the build output? Just copying over the contents of the `build/web` folder should be enough.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in _main.dart.js_ explains why it doesn't work, but doesn't explain what's the cause behind.

Comment: Thanks. I tried two things, (1) using a browser to open the index.html file in the file system, works perfectly. (2) ran an apache server locally and again it worked perfectly. If you want to take a look, here is the whole WebStorm folder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9vlay1qeywgmcf/sudoku_03.7z?dl=0

Comment: I have tried the above on a different computer to a different website, same problem. If I download the uploaded main.dart.js file and attempt to run the web app in a browser using the downloaded file, it doesn't work. i am beginning to suspect the upload is corrupting the file.

Comment: Very possible - are you uploading with FTP? Maybe try setting to binary transfer mode or try it with SFTP instead, if you have that much access to the server.

Comment: Also which version of Dart are running on your machine? `dart --version`

Comment: Tried using binary, file sizes matched exactly (due to CRLF as I work in Windows 10), but app did not run. I do not have access to SFTP.                     Dart version is 1.24.2, using WebStorm 2017.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file main.dart.js fails to load because of a comment at line 32071:

```
// "Document", so we check for the xmlVersion property, which is the empty
```

This is clearly shown in the examples at: `sudoku.geobits.com/index.html` which loads correctly, compared iwth `sudoku.geobits.com/with_comment/index.html` which does not. The difference is that the first does not have the comment, whereas the second is the main.dart.js as generated by WebStorm.

I have logged a bug report:`#30992` with the dart-sdk people.
Thanks to all for their kind help.